# How can I get the output of a batch emacs run to a custom path?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, batch-mode

This works, but the output file is in the same directory as the source file:

```
$ emacs ./notes.org --batch -f org-html-export-to-html --kill
```

How can I get the output in a different directory?

I tried what follows, with no success:

```
$ emacs ./notes.org --batch -f org-html-export-to-html  --eval '(write-file "~/dest/notes.html")' --kill
$ emacs ./notes.org --batch -f org-html-export-to-html > ~/dest/notes.html --kill
$ emacs ./notes.org --batch -f org-html-export-to-html >> ~/dest/notes.html --kill
```

Comment: `org-html-export-to-html` writes its output to `./notes.html`: you don't get a choice. If you want to write to a different file, you will need to use a different function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a different function if you want to control where the export output goes. `org-html-export-to-html` uses the name of the Org mode file and saves it in the same directory with the same name, except that the suffix is changed to `.html` from `.org` (except if `EXPORT_FILE_NAME` is used - see below).

Here is a function that you can use to write the output of the exporter to a different file:

```el
(defun my/org-html-export-to-file (file)
  (let ((output (org-export-as 'html)))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert output)
      (write-file file))))
```

The function stores the output of the exporter as a string and then creates a temporary buffer where it inserts the string - it then saves the buffer to the file given as argument to the function.

Assuming that you have saved the function to a file, say `~/src/emacs/lisp/org-html-to-file.el`, then the command line invocation becomes:

```shell
emacs --batch ./notes.org \
       --load "~/src/emacs/lisp/org-html-to-file.el" \
       --eval '(my/org-html-export-to-file "~/dest/notes.html")'
```

If the destination directory does not exist already, you will be asked whether to create it, which probably defeats the purpose, so you should probably create it in advance.

---

Alternatively, you can add a keyword line like this to your file:

```org
#+EXPORT_FILE_NAME: ~/dest/notes.html
```

See [Export settings](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html).

The command line is simpler, basically what you wrote in your question, but without the (futile) attempt to `eval` a different destination or redirect the output:

```shell
emacs --batch /tmp/foo.org -f org-html-export-to-html
```

Comment: Yes, or you can change the function to take two arguments: the backend and a file; and change the invocation appropriately. As for multiple `EXPORT_FILE_NAME` lines, you can just write `#+EXPORT_FILE_NAME: ~/dest/notes` and let the backend add the suffix.